# "on the attached" or "in the attached"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

1. You can find the information on the attached file.
2. You can find the information in the attached file.

Comment: There are voluminous questions on this site which relate to the choice between "on" and "in". May I suggest you click on this link and look through a few of the answers to see if you can find any clues. And then get back to us if you are still having problems. https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=on+or+in

Comment: For this particular construction, see [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+attached%2Con+the+attached&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20attached%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20attached%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Thank you for the link. But, I couldn't find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The information is within the contents of the file, not placed on top of the file. Therefore, I side with using "in".

By contrast, using "on" feels like there is more to the sentence, like the information *about* the file... something. For example:

> You can find the information on the attached file in the database.

Comment: This clarifies in and on in this type of context.

Answer (score 0):

since the info is "inside" the file as you're going to open it, be it digital or a physical file, I'd go with "in".

Comment: Sometimes it might be 'on' a physical attachment. E.g. the writing is on the page, my article is on the front page etc..  It depends on the exact context.

Answer (score -1):

French "sur" corresponds to English "on."

In either case, the prepositional object is keeping the modified from falling to Earth, or maybe farther... into oblivion. The thing that is under physically supports the thing that is "on."

Alternatively, strictly data-driven, I've never seen a usage in which "on the attached" seemed superior.